# Reading in text file with java (with Tabs)

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, readfile

I keep getting this error. I wasn't sure if the reason was because of the tabs that are contained within the text document. But I can't figure it out!

input file:

```
 Baker, William,        Chavez,     04/01/05,   04/10/06
    Sanchez, Jose,      Chavez,     06/15/05,
    Anderson, Robert,   Wong,       04/02/05,   03/30/06
```

Here is my error:

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:907)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1416)
    at readFile.readFile(readFile.java:26)
    at Tree.main(Tree.java:64)
```

Here is my code for my readFile class! Can't figure it out

```
    import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class readFile {
private Scanner x;


public void openFile(){
    try{
    x = new Scanner(new File("patient.txt"));
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Couldn't find file!");
    }

}

public void readFile(){

    Tree tree = new Tree();
    {
        int key=0;
        while(x.hasNext()){
            String patientName = x.next();
            String doctorName = x.next();
            String currentApp = x.next();
            String nextApp = x.next();
            tree.addNode(key++, patientName, doctorName, currentApp, nextApp);
        }
    }




}
public void closeFile(){
    x.close();
}

}
```

Comment: Where are these methods called?

Comment: Post the text of a sample input file.

Comment: "A Scanner breaks its input into tokens using a delimiter pattern, which by default matches whitespace". This might be the problem for you, try it with explicit whitespaces **or** set the delimiter to a `\t` to make it work for this document. Also, I don't like calling `x.next()` on your scanner 4 times when you don't really know that the next element really exists, that's just asking to throw exceptions or mess up the data when you have an unexpected input format (there are lines with 4 elements for one patient and 1 line where there are 3 elements, you don't do checks for that right now.)

Comment: In the code you show, the constructor accesses uses x.hasNext()  before x has been initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you have a line which more or less than four words.  Note. Scanner.next() reads a word so if you have say

```
one{tab}two three{tab}four{tab}five{newline}
```

This is *five* words.  Once this happens you won't have an exact multiple of four words and your programs will crash as it does.

I suggest you read a line at a time and split using just the tab character instead.

```
while (x.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = x.nextLine();
    if (line.trim().isEmpty()) continue; // skip blank lines.

    String[] parts = line.split("\t", 4);

}
```